# Discrete locks vs lock bits in a shared lock word

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, atomic

I have a situation where it would be useful to be able to atomically obtain more than one lock (possibly all-at-once) from a set of 32 locks, and could potentially replace discrete locks with 32 bits of a shared atomic word, manipulated via atomics, gaining the ability to lock more than one at a time without a complex, error-prone, and costly lock order protocol. (The Linux `FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET` and `FUTEX_WAKE_BITSET` also come in very useful here.)

Does this make sense, and are there performance pitfalls I should worry about? Conceptually, I think the shared lock word should have much higher synchronization costs, since atomics on it must synchronize memory against changes made by other threads under any of the locks, not just the particular locks (bits) being taken. But it also seems likely that this is a purely theoretical difference unless the discrete locks have real, full acquire/release semantics; if they're just implemented with regular barriers that don't tie the memory synchronization to a particular lock address, the synchronization costs should be the same either way.

Is this analysis correct? Are there other reasons I should be cautious about putting multiple lock bits in a single atomic word?

Comment: I think the whole point of multiple locks is to allow them to operate independently. It seems like you're intentionally combining them into one word, which feels counterproductive in terms of performance.

Comment: You're still at risk of deadlock or starvation since multiple locks can be requested/acquired. (You still need to consider things like lock order, etc.) I don't understand what value this lock-bit expression is supposed to give you.

Comment: ^^^ what @e0k says.  If a thread is going to require a subset of multiple locks, then I can't see you gettng away without a comprehensive solution, eg. a lock with a state-machine that can unblock a thread only when all its required resources become free.  In such a case, you can store the state however you want inside the lock.  I doubt that using a 32-bit word, atomic or not, to store the state would win you much in terms of performance and would make testing/debugging harder.  IMHO, ease of testing/debugging always wins when considering such tradeoffs:)

Comment: @e0k: Each controls access to a separate resource, which can be acted upon independently in general. However some operations require operations on one resource to be atomic with a corresponding operation on another resource.

Comment: Storing the lock states as one word instead of many words doesn't fix anything. I don't understand the benefit. You still have to manage issues like starvation. Plus, I'd expect a performance hit from cache invalidation if all those states are in one word of memory and being modified by multiple threads.

Comment: @e0k: The intended advantage is that you can transition atomically from holding no locks to holding locks i, j, and k rather than having to acquire them individually, but maybe that's only an imaginary advantage.